# Fade-in Effect for Modal

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I created a modal dialog in Power Apps canvas asking to confirm a delete:

[image]

It works nicely, but the modal appears abruptly. Does Power Apps have an option to add a slide down/fade in transition effect? My background is in Web Development and Bootstrap, for example, has a nice default animation for modals by adding the "fade" class:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
```

How can I do a similar slide down/fade in animation in Power Apps? If I can't do both, at least a fade in effect so the modal doesn't appear abruptly.

To create my modal, I used standard shapes, a text box and buttons. I then grouped them together:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-the-box, no. But you can use the timer basically.

Set to transparency of the objects to 100%, and a start a timer on a button. Let’s say the timer takes 2 seconds, I.e. 2000 ms.

Now when the button is pressed and the timer starts the transparency can change based on the timer:

```
Transparency =  1 - Timer.Value / 2000
```

You can also set x,y values and make custom slides et cetera for your components.

Comment: Is there a way to set the transparency of a group instead of each object individually? I put all of the elements into a single group.

Comment: Select the group and than modify the transparency (in the fill and colour)